# Calculate balance value between year and year before in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to get a balance value from a df that looks like this

```
df1

Name   Year    Ch1    Origin
A      1995    x1      a
A      1996    x2      b
A      1997    x3      a
A      2000    x4      a
B      1997    y1      c
B      1998    y2      c
```

while Ch1 is numerical. and I want to add an extra col to have this value:

```
Name   Year   Ch1    Bil
A      1995    x1    
A      1996    x2    %
A      1997    x3    %
A      2000    x4    %
B      1997    y1  
B      1998    y2    %
```

I want "Bil" to be `Xi/Xi-1 (value from previous year divided by recent year) IF Xi>=Xi-1` and 
`-Xi-1/Xi IF Xi<Xi-1`
while i is a Year and i-1 is the year before.

I know I can loop this like:

```
for (i in nrow(df1))
  if (df[i,1]==df[i-1,1]) {
      if (df[i,3]>df[i-1,3] {
          df$Bil<-(df[i,3]/df[i-1,3])
      } else df$Bil<-(-df[i-1,3]/df[i,3])
  }
```

Is there a more elegant or quicker way to calculate this? This way I really need to make sure that the dataset is in the right order (going from older to recent years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lag` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  arrange(Year) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(Bil = case_when(Ch1 >= lag(Ch1) ~ Ch1 / lag(Ch1), 
                         Ch1 < lag(Ch1) ~ -lag(Ch1)/Ch1))
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Year = c(1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 2000L, 
1997L, 1998L), Ch1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("x1", "x2", "x3", 
"x4", "y1", "y2"), class = "factor"), Origin = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
df1<-df1 %>% mutate(Ch1 = round(runif(n=6,100,1000),2))
```

Comment: what exactly is not understandable? I can try to rephrase this

Comment: what does lag do? I get an error message when trying to run this. Could the reason be that there is sometime not a Ch1 value for the year before?

Comment: Error:
```# A tibble: 3,396 x 4
# Groups:   Name [943]
   Name        Year    Q14a   Bil
   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Ch1        2010   38000 NA   
 2 Ch1        2011   43200  1.14
 3 Ch1        2012   41080 -1.05
 4 Ch1        2013   43400  1.06
 5 Ch1        2014   43183 -1.01
 6 Ch1        2015   42600 -1.01
...
# ... with 3,386 more rows```

Comment: for some reason the result calculated by the code is not "saved" in the df;
and all NA and negative values are marked red in the Error

Comment: To save the result simply change the first line to `result <- df1 %>%`

Comment: wow how obvious... sometime the simplest errors are the hardest one to solve.. thanks!

Comment: one question: it worked yesterday, but running the code again it results in only 1's , I suppose the function `lag` is masked by another package because when I run `?lag` there are several packages proposed, I tried to do `lag(Ch1, 1)`also didn't change anything. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: You can try replacing each `lag` with `dplyr::lag`.

Comment: worked! Is `lag(Ch1, 1)` the one necessary in that case then?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `data.table` approach using `shift`.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(df1)

dat$value <- rnorm(6, 20, 1) #adding a numeric column 

dat1 <- dat[order(Year)][, 
             Bil := ifelse(test = shift(x = value, n = 1, type = 'lag') > value, 
                           yes = shift(x = value, n = 1, type = 'lag')/value, 
                           no = value/shift(x = value, n = 1, type = 'lag'))]

> dat
   Name Year Ch1 Origin    value
1:    A 1995  x1      a 19.23394
2:    A 1996  x2      b 21.16079
3:    A 1997  x3      a 20.87078
4:    A 2000  x4      a 20.50770
5:    B 1997  y1      c 20.39450
6:    B 1998  y2      c 20.53281

> dat1
   Name Year Ch1 Origin    value      Bil
1:    A 1995  x1      a 19.23394       NA
2:    A 1996  x2      b 21.16079 1.100179
3:    A 1997  x3      a 20.87078 1.013895
4:    B 1997  y1      c 20.39450 1.023353
5:    B 1998  y2      c 20.53281 1.006782
6:    A 2000  x4      a 20.50770 1.001224
```

Comment: This doesnt work, the order is made by Year not Name & Year, hence a wrong estimate is calculatied